# push values from array of objects into new array

Tags: javascript, html

I  have data such as

```
var data = [{"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7},{"2014-01-21":2,"2014-01-22":8}];
```

Now  i  need output as  new

```
data = [ [1,7],[2,8] ]
```

My code outputs [1,2,7,8]  , i  need as [[1,2],[7,8]].

```js
var data = [{
  "2013-01-21": 1,
  "2013-01-22": 7
}, {
  "2014-01-21": 2,
  "2014-01-22": 8
}];

//document.write(data.length)
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

  var json = data[i];
  console.log(json)

  for (var prop in json) {

    result.push(json[prop]);
    console.log(json[prop])

    // or myArray.push(json[prop]) or whatever you want
  }

}

$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `data.map(Object.values);`

Comment: JSON is a string representation of a JS object. Please consider changing your variable names

Comment: I'm too late but `data.map(Object.values)`is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a nested array in the `for` loop.

But there's a built-in function `Object.values()` that will get what you want.

```js
var data = [{
  "2013-01-21": 1,
  "2013-01-22": 7
}, {
  "2014-01-21": 2,
  "2014-01-22": 8
}];
var results = data.map(obj => Object.values(obj));
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values()` gives you the values in each object. And you need to iterate over an array of objects, so:

```js
var data = [{"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7},{"2014-01-21":2,"2014-01-22":8}];



// data = [ [1,7],[2,8] ]


const extracted = data.map( obj => Object.values(obj))

console.log(extracted)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
var data = [{
  "2013-01-21": 1,
  "2013-01-22": 7
}, {
  "2014-01-21": 2,
  "2014-01-22": 8
}];

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  result.push(Object.values(data[i]));
}

$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From MDN - The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop.

This is exactly what you need.

```js
var data = [{"2013-01-21":1,"2013-01-22":7},{"2014-01-21":2,"2014-01-22":8}];

const arr = data.map(x => Object.values(x));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get values array by using `Object.values()`
Solution will be like this:

```js
const data = [{ "2013-01-21": 1, "2013-01-22": 7 }, { "2014-01-21": 2, "2014-01-22": 8 }];
const output = data.map(e => Object.values(e) )
console.log(output)
```